# Touchscreen on Ubuntu 18.04 does not work - X201 Tablet

Tags: 18.04, thinkpad, 18.10, touchscreen

I am a new user to Ubuntu, and I know very few if at all about linux. 
However, I do intend to make the transition and so far everything works well on my X201Tablet out of the box, except the touchscreen.
Can you please guide me through the setup process, if any?

Shay

Answer (score 0):

Solution found!

```
sudo inputattach --daemon -w8001 /dev/ttyS4
```

Voila!